# How to Pick Validation Error in Datagrid bound to Observable Collection (OC)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have an Observable Collection bound to Datagrid.

```
ObservableCollection<Person> PersonOC = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public class Person
{
  public string FName {get;set;}
  public string LName {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
 }

Person p = new Person()

p.FName = "Abc";
p.Lname = "Xyz";
p.Age = 23;

PersonOC.Add(a);

Datagrid.ItemSource = DataOC;
```

When user edits Age column in datagrid, enters non integer character and that cell loses focus it shows validation error by surrounding the cell content with red colour border and an Exclamation sign in Row Header.

So far it works according to my needs.

Now, how do i find out this error has happened in Datagrid so that an update button that saves data in Database becomes deactivated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/ValidationInWPFToolkit.aspx)is a link in Code Project Article on DataGrid Validation..... Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148344/how-do-i-disable-some-controls-based-on-validation-in-wpf/8148807#8148807) is a link to a question on disabling controls based on validation I think taht should do the trick... :)